# Enable Google web activity while disabling purple links

Tags: google-search

I am having a very difficult time finding an answer to this question and am wondering if it is even possible.

I have an Android phone and am rather fond of the Google Now voice assistant. Recently, it appears that the assistant requires that the Web and App activity be turned on. I am perfectly OK with Google tracking and saving my web activity, but I do *not* want Google to show the history when I simply click the search bar, like this:

[image: search, with auto-fill results shown]

Not only does it look cluttered but sometimes my colleagues use my computer and I would rather not have searches that I do at home show up on my work computer. I don't need 10 links of 'photos of [random actress]' showing up any time someone clicks in the search bar.

I am well aware that this option can be disabled by disabling Web Activity, however this also disables the Google Now voice assistant which I would like to keep on.

Does any one know how to leave Search history on, but prevent the web browser from showing the searches?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it involves the interaction of several Android apps. It could be on topic on [android.se].

Comment: @Rubén: I think this is okay on Web Apps, because it's asking about the web interface of Google search, and the instant results seen there. That the data is ultimately from an Android doesn't matter here.

Comment: @TJames: I'm guessing that you've signed in to Google Chrome and/or signed in to your personal account at work. That's the first thing I'd disconnect.

Comment: @ ale I have don't that, however I find myself constantly signing back in to have access to my gmail so it would be nice to just stay signed in.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid, if you don't want web history to be turned off, are either

- don't let co-workers use your browser, or
- disconnect from your Google account while at work